# Detect colored dots in image with tracking js

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a program to count the dots on all the dominoes in a picture, like this:

[image]

I want it to be a JavaScript function. I have tried to understand how to use tracking js with tutorials, but they're all abput face recognition. I only want it to detect colored dots and output how many of them are present in a picture. Is that possible in any way? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can by using some image recognition such as https://trackingjs.com/ or other.